# Simple PHP Soap Server and Client Issue

Tags: php, soap, server, client

I have the following codes copied directly from here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/671437/Creating-Web-Service-Using-PHP-Within-Minutes

Server:

```
    <?php
//call library 
require_once ('nusoap.php'); 
//using soap_server to create server object 
$server = new soap_server; 

//register a function that works on server 
$server->register('get_message'); 

// create the function 
function get_message($your_name) 
{ 
if(!$your_name){ 
return new soap_fault('Client','','Put Your Name!'); 
} 
$result = "Welcome to ".$your_name .". Thanks for Your First Web Service Using PHP with SOAP"; 
return $result; 
} 
// create HTTP listener 
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); 
exit(); 
?>
```

Client:

```
<?php 
require_once ('nusoap.php'); 
//Give it value at parameter 
$param = array( 'your_name' => 'Cool Guy'); 
//Create object that referer a web services 
$client = new soapclient('http://localhost/SOAPServer.php'); 
//Call a function at server and send parameters too 
$response = $client->call('get_message',$param); 
//Process result 
if($client->fault) 
{ 
echo "FAULT: <p>Code: (".$client->faultcode."</p>"; 
echo "String: ".$client->faultstring; 
} 
else 
{ 
echo $response; 
} 
?>
```

When I try to access the client page, it shows me the following error:

> FAULT: Code: (SOAP-ENV:Client
>
> String: error in msg parsing: xml was empty, didn't parse!

I would only need this simple example working, what could be the problem?

Comment: Install soap client

Comment: Should have thought ahead, thanks :)